# npm install etherlime fails

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to install `etherlime` on `Ubuntu 16.04` and `npm 6.5.0`:

`sudo npm install etherlime`

Even if I run the above command with sudo it gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/LimeChain/solidity-coverage.git /home/username/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-823333ab
npm ERR! /home/username/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-823333ab/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/username/.npm/_logs/2019-01-07T08_00_45_775Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used etherlime but you do not need to use `sudo` when using the npm command. Maybe npm is installed in a wrong way or You have an error due to the permissions of your directory.
Try with this:
`sudo chown -R username directory`.

I need the error logs to understand what the problem is, but remember to use npm in a sub-directory and not in the user's home directory.

```
mkdir folderName
cd folderName
npm install etherlime
```

You can found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo) useful.

Obviously before to try this You have to install etherlime globally (`npm install -g etherlime`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
npm i -g etherlime
```

or refer this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/etherlime